# Update viewModels through jquery ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, jquery-tabs, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'd like to implement a product using asp.net mvc.
My Product is devided in several modules and i want to use the jquery tab widget to guide the user trough the submission.
My ProductController sends a list of viewModel objects to the product view.
So my product view looks like this:

```
@model IList<View.Products.Modules.IModuleView>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs({ ajaxOptions:
            {
                type: 'POST', 
                cache: false
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#fragment-1"><span>Tab1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#fragment-2"><span>Tab2</span></a></li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Result","Result","Product")</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="fragment-1">
        @{
            var viewModelA = Model.Where(c => c.GetType() == typeof(WebMvcUI.Models.ModelA)).First();
            var viewModelB = Model.Where(c => c.GetType() == typeof(WebMvcUI.Models.ModelB)).First();
            var viewModelC = Model.Where(c => c.GetType() == typeof(WebMvcUI.Models.ModelC)).First();
        }
        @Html.Partial("viewA", viewModelA)
        @Html.Partial("viewB", viewModelB)
        @Html.Partial("viewC", viewModelC)
    </div>
    <div id="fragment-2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor...
    </div>
</div>
```

So far, so good. When the user clicks on the last tab he invokes the action Result on my ProductController. And here is my Question: What is the best way to collect all form information of my partial views, send it back to the controller and update my viewModels?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

This is my current solution:
(my modules share one form and the Presenter object is stored in the session)

the jQuery:

```
    $('#tabs').bind('tabsselect', function (event, ui) {
        var formToSubmit = $('form:first');
        var jqxhr = $.post(formToSubmit.attr('action'), formToSubmit.serialize(),
            function ShowResult(data) {
                $("#fragment-2").html( data );
            }
        );
    });
```

the Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Result(FormCollection form) 
    {
        viewModelA = (ViewModelA)Presenter.Modules.Where(c => c.GetType() == typeof(WebMvcUI.Models.ViewModelA)).First();
        viewModelB = (ViewModelB)Presenter.Modules.Where(c => c.GetType() == typeof(WebMvcUI.Models.ViewModelB)).First();

        TryUpdateModel<ViewModelA>(viewModelA, form);
        TryUpdateModel<ViewModelB>(viewModelB, form);

        TransactionResult result = Presenter.CheckBusinessRules(true);

        if (result.IsDirty)
        {
            return Content( result.Message);
        }

        return PartialView();
    }
```